# Countdown Redirect Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm writing a code that needs some javascript elements.

Forexample I have a button like this :

```
<button class="butstyle">Click To Redirect</button>
```

I give this button my own css style :

```
.butstyle {
background-color: #e7e7e7;
color: #000000;
}
```

---

I need 4 different things to do, after clicking on it :

1- The text in the button "Click To Redirect", change to "You Will Be Redirect After (*Countdown Timer*)"

2- *Countdown Timer* 20 -> 0, start in the button where I mentioned.

3- The entire button style, change after clicking. Forexample I wanna give this style :

```
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: #ffffff;
border:3px solid #000000;
border-radius:3px;
```

4- When the countdown timer is 0, the page redirect to another page.

---

How can I do all of them, in an onclick function?

Comment: What did you try yourself so far?, because if you take 1 step at the time, it fairly easy to find guide if you google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your button an "id" (for easier implementation) and use the following code:

```
$('#myButton').on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('#myButton').removeClass().addClass('butAfter').text('You will be redirected in: 20 seconds');
var counter = 20;
var int = setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    $('#myButton').text('You will be redirected in: '+counter+' seconds');

    if (counter == 0) {

        clearInterval(int);
        //do your nex action here
    }
}, 1000);

});
```

Also another class should be declared in your css to perform the after click button changes:

```
.butAfter{
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: #ffffff;
border:3px solid #000000;
border-radius:3px;
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/skohg9zL/1/

Hope that helps you!

EDIT:

I made some changes to javascript code to fix the error you mentioned:

```
var counter = 20;
$('.butstyle').on('click',function(e){

e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();

if($(this).hasClass('butstyle')){

$('.butstyle').text('You will be redirected in: 20 seconds');
$(this).removeClass().addClass('butAfter');

var int = setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    $('.butAfter').text('You will be redirected in: '+counter+' seconds');

    if (counter == 0) {

        clearInterval(int);
        counter = 20;
        $('#myButton').removeClass().addClass('butstyle').text('Click To Redirect');
        //do your next action here:

    }
}, 1000);

}

});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/skohg9zL/6/

Comment: thanks for your asnwer. How can i fix the problem, that when i click on the button twise, the timer goes faster.

Comment: @AmirEbrahimi I have made some changes. Pls, see the above updated code. Also, if my answer solved your issue, please accept it... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**I hop Your Answer This**

*After Click Change Style then Add Script*

```
$('.butstyle').removeClass('butstyle').addClass('AfterChange');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/k8k85sg0/2/)**

```js
$('.butstyle').click(function() {
  var count = 20;
 var Interval= setInterval(function() {
    count--;
    $('.butstyle').removeClass('butstyle').addClass('AfterChange');
    document.getElementById('butstyle').innerHTML = 'Countdown Timer ' + count;
    if (count == 0) {
      alert('Now Redirect To other page');
      // similar behavior as clicking on a link
      window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
     clearInterval(Interval);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="butstyle" id="butstyle">Click To Redirect</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we are..only Javascript

```js
var button=document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
   button.style.color='#ffffff';
   button.style.backgroundColor='#4CAF50';
   button.style.border=' 3px solid #000000';
   button.style.borderRadius='3px';
   var i=0;
   var tt=setInterval(function(){     
   i=i+1;
   var counter=20-i;
   button.innerHTML='You Will Be Redirect After:'+counter;
     if(counter===0){
       clearInterval(tt);
       window.location = "http://www.google.com";
     }
     
   },1000);
   
});
```

```css
.butstyle {
background-color: #e7e7e7;
color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->

<button class="butstyle" id="button">Click To Redirect</button>

<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```